# Calling method in superview from subview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiview

I have looked through the site for answers but nothing seem to have helped me

This is my scenario
I have a main view called settingsView.
A subview, AboutView is called from settingsView using the following

```
        aboutView = [[AboutView alloc] initWithNibName:@"AboutView" bundle:nil];
        CGRect theFrame = aboutView.view.frame;
        theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(330,50);
        aboutView.view.frame = theFrame;
        theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,50);
        theFrame.size.width=320;
        theFrame.size.height=360;       
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        aboutView.view.frame = theFrame;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [self.view addSubview:aboutView.view];
```

I would like to call a method or even viewDidAppear method in settingsView once aboutView is dismissed.

I have tried almost all the ways i could find in this forum

In the aboutView, i have tried
[self.view.superview viewDidAppear];
[self.parentViewControllers ...] //Returns null, since i am not using presentViewController

I have read suggestions on setting delegate, but for whatever reason i cannot set the delegate for the aboutView.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)viewController {
    for (UIView* next = [self.view superview]; next; next = next.superview) {
        UIResponder* nextResponder = [next nextResponder];
        if ([nextResponder isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            [(UIViewController*)nextResponder viewWillAppear:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the above code from Three20 library. Defined a method in the subview and called it. It works, but is this the right way to do it? Any other simpler way?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I don't know if it's a good practice or not. What do you think?